# How I can add root CA to minikube?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

My company uses it's own root CA and when I'm trying to pull images. Even from a private registry I'm getting error:

> 1h     3m      22  {kubelet minikube}          Warning     FailedSync  Error syncing
>   pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "POD" with ErrImagePull:
>   "image pull failed for gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0, this
>   may be because there are no credentials on this request.
>
> details:
>   (Error response from daemon: Get https://gcr.io/v1/_ping: x509:
>   certificate signed by unknown authority)"
>       1h    10s 387 {kubelet minikube}      Warning FailedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "POD" with
>   ImagePullBackOff: "Back-off pulling image
>   \"gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0\""

How I can install root CA to minkube or avoid this message i.e. Use only private registry, and don't pull anything from `gcr.io` ?

Comment: Hey could you maybe consider to update your question so it's easier to reproduce your issues?

Comment: Unfortunately it is impossible, because you need to be behind special software which will replace root CA

Comment: @gerdi, your edit made the question unreadable.. please revert

Comment: @VincentDeSmet hi, thanks for your feedback ,could you pls explain how it is not readable?

Comment: Pls also consider editing it to change it accordingly. thanks

Comment: @arykalin Hi! Did you solve the problem? I tried `--insecure-registry` but still get x509

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only solution I've found so far is adding --insecure-registry gcr.io option to the minikube.

Comment: `--insecure-registry="gcr.io"`?

Comment: what if you need to add more than one insecure registry?

Comment: Or possibly `--insecure-registry k8s.gcr.io`

Comment: A [note](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/604#issuecomment-247813764) for when I inevitably forget: "the `--insecure-registry` flag is ignored if the machine already existed (even if it is stopped). You must first `minikube delete` if you want new flags to be respected".

Comment: @DavidWest this option value may be an array.

Answer (score 5):

To address:

```
x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Could you please try the following suggestion from Minikube repo?

> copy the cert into the VM. The location should be:
>
> /etc/docker/certs.d/
>
> from here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/certificates/

[ref](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/311#issuecomment-231846380)

That thread also includes the following one-liner:

```
cat <certificatefile> \
  | minikube ssh "sudo mkdir -p /etc/docker/certs.d/<domain> && sudo tee /etc/docker/certs.d/<domain>/ca.crt"
```

The issue here is the CA Trust chain of the Linux host that needs to be updated. The easiest way is to reboot the Linux host after copying the certs into the VM, if rebooting is not an option - look for a way to `update-ca-certificates`.

Just restarting the Docker Daemon will most likely not solve this issue

Note: allowing the Docker daemon to use insecure registries means certificates aren't verified.. while this may help, it does not solve the question asked here

Comment: Yes, creating /etc/docker/certs.d/gcr.io and putting root CA there helped. Thanks.

Comment: Hm, no, sorry, look like it don't.    
```docker pull gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0
3.0: Pulling from google_containers/pause-amd64
a3ed95caeb02: Downloading 
f11233434377: Downloading 
x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Comment: did you try restarting minikube? It could be the certs are loaded from the certs folder during boot process? - The blog article I linked does mention a restart is required as well.

Comment: Hm, I tried to restart docker daemon, if I'm restarting minikube it don't keep my changes and I can't find a way to keep them.

Comment: docker daemon is not the one trusting the certs here... it's the linux distro used by minikube that needs to add the certs you copied into the certs dir to its trust chain. I'm not sure if minikube is alpine based, but you could try something similar to this: https://github.com/so0k/docker-efk/blob/master/log-generator/Dockerfile#L5-L8 (load certs from a dir)

Comment: oh, it's different, this is `keytool` from Java to load certs to the Java Key Store...

Comment: if you can't / wont reboot the Linux host, you basically need to run the `update-ca-certificates` tool for the applicable distro... (docker daemon reloads don't help here)

Answer (score 1):

You can add your companies certificate into the minikube kubernetes cluster by first copying the certificate to `$HOME/.minikube/certs`:

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.minikube/certs
cp my-company.pem $HOME/.minikube/certs/my-company.pem
```

And then starting minikube with the `--embed-certs` option:

```
minikube start --embed-certs
```

Source: [Official documentation](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/untrusted_certs/)

Answer (score 0):

A straight forward way to do this independent from minikube would be to use a `imagePullSecrets` configuration. As documented in the [Pulling an Image from a Private Registry](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/) guide, you can create a `Secret` and use that along with your image like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: demo-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: private-container
      image: <your-private-image>
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: the_secret
```

Where the `the_secret` could be created with:

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry the_secret --docker-server=xxx --docker-username=xxx --docker-password=xxx --docker-email=xxx
```

Or with:

```
kubectl create secret generic the_secret --from-file=.docker/config.json
```

Or with anything else which is related to `kubectl create secret` - see [documentation for details](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_create_secret/).

---

*Edit:* Even in the official `minikube` documentation you'll find that they use `Secrets` along with the `registry-creds` addon.

You'll find the generic documentation [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube#private-container-registries) and the documentation for the addon [here](https://github.com/upmc-enterprises/registry-creds).

It burns down to:

```
minikube addons enable registry-creds
```

But technically it does the same as described above.

Comment: seems the issue is more related to ca trust chain in which case the ca cert needs to be added to the ca-certificates folder of the minikube host OS... I assume something similar to the following is needed - http://docker-saigon.github.io/post/Private-Registry-Setup/#4-ensuring-your-docker-engine-can-push-pull-from-this-registry:21a6fde08c8e60098cde90e87b1d737a

Comment: Yes. My company gave me a doc in which it said to put root CA to /usr/share/ca-certificates/ and then run dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates or update-ca-trust enable. The problem is that minikube don't have one of this commands and I don't know how to enable my company's root ca. Putting it to the /etc/docker/certs.d/<domain>  didn't help.

Comment: @arykalin - I'm not sure what the distro is of minikube, can you check `cat /etc/*release*` and let me know? if it's alpine you may need to `apk install --no-cache ca-certificates 
&& update-ca-certificates`

Comment: I tried this but it didn't help. Also changin something inside minikube system itself won't persists after restart.