# Minikube: Path to Root Certificate

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am using Minikube/Kubernetes and want to *add* a new user. Therefore I need to sign the certificate request for a this new user. Where is the root certificate of Minikube located?

Comment: Hi, check it out the answers of the this question 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42646109/how-i-can-add-root-ca-to-minikube?rq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find your Minikube CA certificate(s) in your `~/.minikube` directory.